# Как перенести данные из одной бд в другую?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Здравствуйте.Есть приложение на Java JPA и база данных mysql, с которой это приложение взаимодействует.Я создал еще одну бд mysql, в которую хочу перенести часть данных из первой. Как работать с двумя базами в одном приложении? Создавать две единицы персистентности?

Comment: возможно будет проще использовать SQL, особенно если данных много. вы используете чистый JPA?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring), похоже Ваш случай.